# Remote location: no access, or does not exist/offline?

Tags: powershell, authentication

I'm making a PowerShell script that will allow the user to move certain local files to a certain server. To ease the process I want to check if the user has access to the server or not, and if not, I want to prompt for a username/password.

Using `Test-Path` I can check whether or not the user can access specific remote location. However, if Test-Path fails, there is no way of knowing if it's because the remote location does not exist, or because the user does not have sufficient rights.

I'm looking for a way to:

- Find out if the user has access to a remote location (could use Test-Path for this)
- (*if above failed*) Find out if this is because the remote location is unavailable or because the user does not have sufficient rights
- (*depending on above*) Show error message or prompt for credentials

Of course I could Test-Path, ask for credentials if necessary, and then Test-Path again. But I'm trying to find a nicer solution.

Comment: I assume when you are talking about a remote location you are talking about a path on a server and not the server itself, so Test-Connection won't work?

Comment: Hmmm, I could at least use Test-Connection to verify the server exists and is reachable. I think I can work with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Test-Connection` to see if the server exists. This is not a fool-proof method though because not all servers and other devices that may be in the network path respond to ICMP requests, which is what `Test-Connection` and `ping` use.

Comment: I finally used `Test-Connection` first to check if the server is reachable. Then followed up with a `Test-Path`, assuming the path on the server exists, I'm also assuming that if this fails, it's because of insufficient privileges.